# RegEx, сложный парсинг строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, помогите написать регулярку, и можно ли вобще в данном случае ее написать?
На входе строка:

```html
ss.aa=x.zv xyz (ss.abc=p.efg wtp op.prm xx yyy cbrx) xxx ac.poi>bc.oo rty ac.poi<zc.oo
```

а должны из нее получить строку:

```html
'ss'.'aa'='x'.'zv' xyz ('ss'.'abc'='p'.'efg' wtp 'op'.'prm' xx yyy cbrx) xxx 'ac.'poi>'bc'.'oo' rty 'ac'.'poi'<'zc'.'oo'
```

В общем опираться тут нужно на точки и пробелы, начало и конец строки. То что разделено точкой должно быть обернуто кавычками. Как по мне, это мега-сложно. Помогите это сделать! Благодарен за ваше бесценное время)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абсолютно ничего сложного. Нас интересует только конструкция `xx.xx`, а начало-конец строки, пробелы не интересуют совершенно. Ищем все, что находится слева и справа от точки, и обрамляем кавычками:

```
/([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)/'$1'.'$2'/g
```

- `[a-z]+` - один или больше символов в диапазоне [a-z]. если встречаются другие символы, их тоже добавить.
- `\.` - символ точки
- `$1`, `$2` - найденные значения из первой и второй скобки
- `g` - глобальный модификатор для поиска по всей строке

```js
string = "ss.aa=x.zv xyz (ss.abc=p.efg wtp op.prm xx yyy cbrx) xxx ac.poi>bc.oo rty ac.poi<zc.oo";
regexp = /([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)/g;
alert(string.replace(regexp, "'$1'.'$2'"));
```